# How to return successfully parsed rows that converted into my case class

Tags: scala, spray-json

I have a file, each row is a json array.
I reading each line of the file, and trying to convert the rows into a json array, and then for each element I am converting to a case class using json spray.

I have this so far:

```
       for (line <- source.getLines().take(10)) {
          val jsonArr = line.parseJson.convertTo[JsArray]
          for (ele <- jsonArr.elements) {
            val tryUser = Try(ele.convertTo[User]) 
          }
        }
```

How could I convert this entire process into a single line statement?

```
val users: Seq[User] = source.getLines.take(10).map(line => line.parseJson.convertTo[JsonArray].elements.map(ele => Try(ele.convertTo[User])
```

The error is:

> found : Iterator[Nothing]

Comment: Shouldn't be `JsArray` instead of `JsonArray`? Also return type is `Iterator[Vector[Try[User]]]` instead of `Seq[User]`. Except that the code seems to compile https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/VHXD9kTCQhGNZjPd0YcKRQ/5

Answer (score 0):

Note: I used Scala 2.13.6 for all my examples.

---

There is a lot to unpack in these few lines of code. First of all, I'll share some code that we can use to generate some meaningful input to play around with.

```
object User {

  import scala.util.Random

  private def randomId: Int = Random.nextInt(900000) + 100000
  private def randomName: String = Iterator
    .continually(Random.nextInt(26) + 'a')
    .map(_.toChar)
    .take(6)
    .mkString

  def randomJson(): String = s"""{"id":$randomId,"name":"$randomName"}"""
  def randomJsonArray(size: Int): String =
    Iterator.continually(randomJson()).take(size).mkString("[", ",", "]")

}

final case class User(id: Int, name: String)

import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

import spray.json._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._

implicit val UserFormat = jsonFormat2(User.apply)
```

This is just some scaffolding to define some `User` domain object and come up with a way to generate a JSON representation of an array of such objects so that we can then use a JSON library (`spray-json` in this case) to parse it back into what we want.

Now, going back to your question. This is a possible way to massage your data into its parsed representation. It may not fit 100% what your are trying to do, but there's some nuance in the data types involved and how they work:

```
val parsedUsers: Iterator[Try[User]] =
  for {
    line <- Iterator.continually(User.randomJsonArray(4)).take(10)
    element <- line.parseJson.convertTo[JsArray].elements
  } yield Try(element.convertTo[User])
```

First difference: notice that I use the `for` comprehension in a form in which the "outcome" of an iteration is not a side effect (`for (something) { do something }`) but an actual value `for (something) yield { return a value }`).

Second difference: I explicitly asked for an `Iterator[Try[User]]` rather than a `Seq[User]`. We can go very down into a rabbit hole on the topic of why the types are what they are here, but the simple explanation is that a `for ... yield` expression:

1. returns the same type as the one in the first line of the generation -- if you start with a `val ns: Iterator[Int]; for (n<- ns) ...` you'll get an iterator at the end
2. if you nest generators, they *need* to be of the same type as the "outermost" one

You can read more on `for` comprehensions on the [Tour of Scala](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/for-comprehensions.html) and the [Scala Book](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/for-expressions.html).

One possible way of consuming this is the following:

```
for (user <- parsedUsers) {
  user match {
    case Success(user)  => println(s"parsed object $user")
    case Failure(error) => println(s"ERROR: '${error.getMessage}'")
  }
```

---

As for how to turn this into a "one liner", `for` comprehensions are syntactic sugar applied by the compiler which turns every nested call into a `flatMap` and the final one into `map`, as in the following example (which yields an equivalent result as the `for` comprehension above and very close to what the compiler does automatically):

```
val parsedUsers: Iterator[Try[User]] = Iterator
  .continually(User.randomJsonArray(4))
  .take(10)
  .flatMap(line =>
    line.parseJson
      .convertTo[JsArray]
      .elements
      .map(element => Try(element.convertTo[User]))
  )
```

One note that I would like to add is that you should be mindful of readability. Some teams prefer `for` comprehensions, others manually rolling out their own `flatMap`/`map` chains. Coders discretion is advised.

---

You can play around with this code [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/5kvGz9h1SKWN2AtMARg3ow) (and [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/5kvGz9h1SKWN2AtMARg3ow/2) is the version with the `flatMap`/`map` calls).